# Connection threashhold exeeded, while loadbalancing tomcat. with apache, and mod_jk

Tags: apache, tomcat, load-balancing, mod-jk

I inherited a java webapp running on two tomcat instances, and load balanced by apache2.2 mod_jk 1.2.19. This connects to a DB on a separate server. 4 servers in total.

The DB admin noted for the last couple of days a sudden increase in application connections to the database at certain times which then automatically reduces after few minutes. This is causing the maximum number of sessions to run out in the database.

I would really appreciate if you can have a look at the below, and give some advice.

The workers.properties file is as follows.

```
# Define list of workers that will be used
# for mapping requests
worker.list=loadbalancer,status

# Define tomcatA
# modify the host as your host IP or DNS name.
worker.tomcatA.port=8009
worker.tomcatA.host=10.1.26.21
worker.tomcatA.type=ajp13
worker.tomcatA.lbfactor=1
worker.tomcatA.cachesize=10
worker.tomcatA.socket_keepalive=1
worker.tomcatA.socket_timeout=30
worker.tomcatA.connection_pool_timeout=600
worker.tomcatA.connect_timeout=60000
# Define tomcatB as the failover for tomcatA
worker.tomcatA.redirect=tomcatB

# Define tomcatB
# modify the host as your host IP or DNS name.
worker.tomcatB.port=8009
worker.tomcatB.host=10.1.26.23
worker.tomcatB.type=ajp13
worker.tomcatB.lbfactor=1
worker.tomcatB.cachesize=10
worker.tomcatB.socket_keepalive=1
worker.tomcatB.socket_timeout=30
worker.tomcatB.connection_pool_timeout=600
worker.tomcatB.connect_timeout=60000
# Define tomcatA as the failover for tomcatB
worker.tomcatB.redirect=tomcatA

# Load-balancing behaviour
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
# Setting the number of retries for a worker
worker.retries=4
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=tomcatA,tomcatB
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=1
# worker.list=loadbalancer

# Status worker for managing load balancer
worker.status.type=status
```

The error below started appearing in the mod_jk log.

`[Wed Nov 16 09:49:27 2016] [1380:5076] [error] jk_ajp_common.c (947): (tomcatB) can't receive the response message from tomcat, network problems or tomcat is down (10.1.26.23:8009), err=-60
[Wed Nov 16 09:49:27 2016] [1380:5076] [error] jk_ajp_common.c (1536): (tomcatB) Tomcat is down or refused connection. No response has been sent to the client (yet)
[Wed Nov 16 09:49:47 2016] [1380:4332] [error] jk_ajp_common.c (947): (tomcatA) can't receive the response message from tomcat, network problems or tomcat is down (10.1.26.21:8009), err=-60
[Wed Nov 16 09:49:47 2016] [1380:4332] [error] jk_ajp_common.c (1536): (tomcatA) Tomcat is down or refused connection. No response has been sent to the client (yet)
[Wed Nov 16 09:49:47 2016] [1380:4332] [error] jk_ajp_common.c (1879): (tomcatA) Connecting to tomcat failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port`

tomcat catalina logs

```
Nov 15, 2016 11:54:14 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket processConnection
WARNING: processCallbacks status 2
Nov 15, 2016 11:57:25 PM org.apache.jk.core.MsgContext action
WARNING: Error sending end packet
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.send(ChannelSocket.java:518)
    at org.apache.jk.common.JkInputStream.endMessage(JkInputStream.java:112)
    at org.apache.jk.core.MsgContext.action(MsgContext.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:182)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.finish(Response.java:304)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:204)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:282)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:754)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:684)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:876)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:685)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

there is 15000 lines in the catalina from 6am to 12pm containing that exact paragraph. the only other 8 lines are below. It only appeared once .

```
джЭ 15, 2016 6:41:11 г org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket processConnection
WARNING: processCallbacks status 2
джЭ 15, 2016 6:43:49 г org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector memberDisappeared
INFO: Received memberDisappeared[org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://ptahq27escan1.scan.internal:4000,ptahq27escan1.scan.internal,4000, alive=188815394,id={60 83 112 -109 -10 -107 69 87 -112 -21 -49 103 -100 -111 -8 84 }, payload={}, command={}, domain={}, ]] message. Will verify.
джЭ 15, 2016 6:43:50 г org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector memberDisappeared
INFO: Verification complete. Member still alive[org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://ptahq27escan1.scan.internal:4000,ptahq27escan1.scan.internal,4000, alive=188815394,id={60 83 112 -109 -10 -107 69 87 -112 -21 -49 103 -100 -111 -8 84 }, payload={}, command={}, domain={}, ]]
джЭ 15, 2016 6:55:26 г org.apache.jk.core.MsgContext action
WARNING: Error sending end packet
```

in the server.xml the following connectionTimeouts are set

```
<!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
     and responses are returned. Documentation at :
     Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
     Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
     APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
     Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
-->
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           maxThreads="660" connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="WINDOWS-1256" />

<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" connectionTimeout="20000" URIEncoding="WINDOWS-1256"  />
```

let me know if there is any additional details needed
regards

Comment: First of all since you are using mod_jk, you can comment out the HTTP connector at 8080 on your server.xml.

Could you provide (in pastebin probably) more catalina logs? Especially just before the snippet you pasted.

Also, when the problem occurs you need to perform a thread dump on the tomcat instance(s) and examine and provide the output. There is a possibility that the running threads will reveal what tomcat is busy with and provide an answer.